# A MySQL query that will run checks from Two tables and if true show in C# datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, datagridview

I am trying to develop a way using MySQL query and a C# datagridview to show all customers that pay more than the price asked.

I believe the best way is to query all customers that if Donation is greater than Price then Show.

**Animals Table**

```
| Specie  | Price |  Stock  | Country   |
|---------|-------|---------|-----------|
| Dog     |  20   |    5    |   UK      |
| Cat     |  10   |    0    |   UK      |
| Dog     |  20   |    34   |   France  |
| Cat     |  10   |    234  |   France  |
| Dog     |  20   |    0    |   Germany |
| Cat     |  10   |    14   |   Germany |
```

**Customer Table**

```
|  Name     | Specie | Price |  DonationPound | DonationEuro | Country   |
|-----------|--------|-------|----------------|--------------|-----------|
|   Tom     | Dog    |       |    200         |   323        |   UK      |
|   Ben     | Dog    |       |    120         |   288        |   UK      |
|   Greg    | Dog    |       |    50          |   23         |   Germany |
|   Sally   | Cat    |       |    234         |   123        |   France  |
|   Mitch   | Dog    |       |    111         |   89         |   France  |
|   Steve   | Cat    |       |    143         |   56         |   UK      |
```

*`Specie` and `Country` are input into the `Customer Table` via a Selected value insert from a drop down list populated from `Country` and `Specie` in the `Animal Table`*.

- I am trying work out a query to add the `price` from `Animals Table`
  into Customers.

**What I need**

I need a query that will populate a datagridview of all `Customers` that `Donated` More than the `price`.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
**!!!Solution!!!**//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
SELECT c.* FROM Customer c 
INNER JOIN Animals a 
  ON c.Specie=a.Specie AND c.Country=a.Country 
WHERE c.Donation_Pound > a.Price OR c.Donation_Euro > a.Price
```

Thanks to @Marco who provided a query I altered to fit my needs

Comment: Which donation field is the comparison on?

Comment: Both of them as one is for the euro but in the table I have converted in to pounds so both currency need comparing to price.

Comment: Price in animals table is in pounds or in euros?

Comment: Pounds and donation pounds and euros are both in pounds, its the front end they differ, but once they are server side they are all pounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
SELECT c.* FROM customers c
INNER JOIN animals a 
  ON c.Specie=a.Specie AND c.Country=a.Country
WHERE c.DonationPound > a.Price
```

Naturally I'm guessing which prices need to be compared...

Comment: bot donation pounds and euros need comparing to price and if higher then called in datagrid. its the front end that euro is converted to euro.

Comment: I'm lost: you need to use same measures if you want to compare items. So, to query items you need a default currency...

Comment: so I need to compare euro & pounds to Price. As euro and pounds are the same currency in the table